# What will happen when we don't override the run method for Thread class? Will it's state change or not?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

What will happen if we don't override the run method present in Thread class?
Will it's state change from Start -> Runnable/Running ever? Or will it go from NEW -> Terminated.

Comment: @user16320675, maybe not so easy to test. The new thread should, in theory, transition through the `RUNNABLE` state, but it will spend so little time there that, in practice, it might be near impossible to ever _see_ it in that state.

Answer (score 1):

If you create `t=new Thread()`, and then you call `t.start()`, it's life cycle will be the same as the life cycle of any other thread. But, it will be short-lived because you did not provide a `Runnable` delegate in the constructor call, and without any delegate, the default `run()` method will immediately return.

Comment: Agreed, but does its state change or not?

Comment: @LovVerma, Yes, It's state will change. When I said, "same life cycle," I meant that the new thread must progress through the same sequence of states as any other pure computation thread. The new thread doesn't _literally_ do nothing. It must do some small amount of work before it can call the `run` method (e.g., it must look up which `run` method to call in the `Thread` object's vtable) and it must do some small amount of work after `run` returns (e.g., it must figure out whether a call to the Thread object's `uncaughtExceptionHandler` is needed.)